# Load a local image after loading a remote image failed

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to load a local image if the remote image failed?

For example, I have the following code:

```
<Image style={ styles.userImage }
       source={ { uri: http://example.com/my_image.jpg } }
       onError={(error) => ...}
/>
```

In case for example I don't have the rights to access `http://example.com/my_image.jpg`, I'll get an error in `onError`. Is there a way then to load a local image instead?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use component' state. In your constructor set initial url:

```
 this.state = { image: { uri: 'http://example.com/my_image.jpg' } }
```

Create `onError` handler:

```
 onError(error){
   this.setState({ image: require('your_local_image.path')})
 }
```

And then combine it all together:

```
 <Image style={ styles.userImage }
       source={ this.state.image }
       onError={ this.onError.bind(this) }
 />
```

Comment: I've tried it and onError has never been called in iOS. I've tried a img link with 404 error.

Comment: if we get image from array than how we used  this.state = { image: { uri: 'http://example.com/my_image.jpg' } }

Comment: Check out my answer @AnkushThakur I think it might be what you're looking for. It allows you to pass in an array of possible images.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I inserted a log statement to check if the onError function is being called, and it is. However the `<Image>` component does not update with the expected backup image. Does it require something to manually trigger a re-draw or something?

Answer (score 34):

As per the latest docs you can use `defaultSource` property. It shows the image till the original image loads, if the load fails the default image is shown [Link to docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#defaultsource)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as of today. There's no need to create pointless state.

Comment: This answer is simple and clean. By the way, if you are using FastImage lib, then you can use fallback prop right before defaultSource prop to fallback to Image component. Default Source will work this way.

Comment: If it doesn't work - Please note default source is ignored in debug builds

Comment: Still should be the accepted answer as of today!

Comment: In docs it should say the default image will be shown in case of failure as well. It just says it will show while image loads. Btw good answer.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. If the image is missing, the `<Image>` component just shows a blank screen?

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate on Cherniv's answer you could create an `<Images />` component that abstracts this away for you:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image } from 'react-native';

export default class Images extends React.Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    source: [],
    onError: () => {},
  }

  state = { current: 0 }

  onError = error => {
    this.props.onError(error);
    const next = this.state.current + 1;
    if (next < this.props.source.length) {
      this.setState({ current: next });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { onError, source, ...rest } = this.props;
    return (
      <Image
        source={source[this.state.current]}
        onError={this.onError}
        {...rest}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
import Images from './Images';

<Images
  source={[
    { uri: 'http://example.com/bad_image.jpg' },
    { uri: 'http://example.com/good_image.jpg' },
    require('./default.jpg'),
  ]}
  style={{
    backgroundColor: '#ccc',
    height: 200,
    width: 200,
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a component ImageLoad like this:

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Image, ImageBackground, ActivityIndicator, View } from 'react-native';

class ImageLoad extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    isShowActivity: PropTypes.bool,
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    isShowActivity: true,
    };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoaded: false,
      isError: false
    };
  }

  onLoadEnd(){
    this.setState({
      isLoaded: true
    });
  }

  onError(){
    this.setState({
      isError: true
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      style, source, resizeMode, borderRadius, backgroundColor, children,
      loadingStyle, placeholderSource, placeholderStyle,
      customImagePlaceholderDefaultStyle
    } = this.props;
    return(
      <ImageBackground
        onLoadEnd={this.onLoadEnd.bind(this)}
        onError={this.onError.bind(this)}
        style={[styles.backgroundImage, style]}
        source={source}
        resizeMode={resizeMode}
        borderRadius={borderRadius}
      >
        {
          (this.state.isLoaded && !this.state.isError) ? children :
          <View
            style={[styles.viewImageStyles, { borderRadius: borderRadius }, backgroundColor ? { backgroundColor: backgroundColor } : {}]}
          >
            {
              (this.props.isShowActivity && !this.state.isError) &&
              <ActivityIndicator
                style={styles.activityIndicator}
                size={loadingStyle ? loadingStyle.size : 'small'}
                color={loadingStyle ? loadingStyle.color : 'gray'}
              />
            }
            <Image
              style={placeholderStyle ? placeholderStyle : [styles.imagePlaceholderStyles, customImagePlaceholderDefaultStyle]}
              source={placeholderSource ? placeholderSource : require('./Images/empty-image.png')}
            >
            </Image>
          </View>
        }
        {
          this.props.children &&
          <View style={styles.viewChildrenStyles}>
          {
            this.props.children
          }
          </View>
        }
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  backgroundImage: {
    position: 'relative',
  },
  activityIndicator: {
    position: 'absolute',
    margin: 'auto',
    zIndex: 9,
  },
  viewImageStyles: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#e9eef1',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  imagePlaceholderStyles: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  viewChildrenStyles: {
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    position: 'absolute',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  }
}

export default ImageLoad;
```

and use this anywhere in your app:

```
<ImageLoad
    style={{ width: 320, height: 250 }}
    loadingStyle={{ size: 'large', color: 'blue' }}
    source={{ uri: 'url image' }}
/>
```